# NullReferenceException when accessing @User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net-core

We are running an ASP net core 2.1 website. In the header of the page, we want to display the name of the current user. The variable is retrieved through the windows authentication scheme using the @User.Identity.Name reference and is assembled like this: ZH_MB\rohzeh, where ZH_MB is the domain and rohzeh the windows AD user. Because we just want the username, we split both loike this:

```
<p class="pull-right navbar-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> @User.Identity.Name.Split("\\")[1]</p>
```

Now when we run this code, we get the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.b__46_1() in
>   _Layout.cshtml, line 111

Line 111 is the code above. When I run it without the split part like this:

```
 <p class="pull-right navbar-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> @User.Identity.Name</p>
```

It works just fine, except for the domain information that I don't want.

When i surround this code with a try/catch block, it works as expected, showing only the user name:

```
@try
        {
        <p class="pull-right navbar-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> @User.Identity.Name.Split("\\")[1]</p>            
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException) { }
```

Any idea what the problem might be? My initial idea was: the information is just not ready when the page is rendered. But in this case, the second line of could should provide the same error.

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` could potentially be null (and in fact *is* in your scenario). Any time something could be null (and strings can *always* be null), you need to plan for that by actually checking for a null value first, or just doing something like `User.Identity.Name?.Split("\\")[1]`. The `?` will return null immediately if the value preceding it is null, and only call subsequent methods (i.e. `Split`) if there's an actual value to operate on. As for *why* your user is null, you probably haven't enabled Windows Auth correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems

- your user is not authenticated yet or `Name` is null
- or you didn't install [ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle for IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module)
- or you didn't configure all needed [to use Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth)
- or forwarding Windows Authentication is set to false for some reasons

You can set it this way or [others](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2017/06/26/how-to-support-windows-authentication-for-asp-net-core-in-iis/):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true);
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the answer of Chris Pratt did the trick. I could replace the try/catch with the "?" and the username is shown corrently.